# Почему при выдачи index.php через try_files $uri/index.php не работает php?

Tags: php, nginx

Есть сервер, который около года использовал только ради прокси
Тут захотел поучиться писать что-то простенькое на PHP и столкнулся с проблемой

При запросе site.com выдаётся index.php, лежащий в корне (классика). Но проблема в том, что php скрипт не обрабатывается. Если же обратиться к site.com/index.php, то php обрабатывается нормально. Вроде настройки nginx выставил правильно, а что-то никак...

Конфиг сервера:

```
location / {
    autoindex off;
    try_files $uri/index.php $uri/index.html =404;
  }
location ~ \.php$ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php =404; 
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
  }
```

PHP 7.0, там настройки, вроде, не трогал

В Гугле искал, но либо искал неправильно, либо подобного в Гугле нет (скорее первое)

**Решение:**
Добавил

```
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

в location / {...}. Теперь всё работает исправно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обращении к *site.com* *nginx* пользуется `location /`, а для него у вас не объявлен `fastcgi_pass`.